# Syncing iPhone with Shotwell

Tags: iphone, shotwell

Is it possible to have Shotwell automatically sync with my iPhone so I have my picture library on both?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, no free/open source software (including Shotwell) is capable of this.  It's one of the sad facts of life that comes with using a proprietary device.

As a Shotwell developer and iPhone user, believe me, I'd **love** to see this. But it's unlikely to happen (barring some decision to open up on Apple's part.)

Comment: What is the exact technical reason for failing importing photos from iPhone?

Comment: Is this answer obsolete? I see reports of some people using iPhones and Shotwell successfully, so perhaps someone has figured out a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Shotwell should open automatically when the iPhone is plugged in if you have set it to manage your photos by default, however it only allows you to import photos manually and has no syncing feature AFAIK.

You can [read details on how to import photos on their site here](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/index.html#import)

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu 17.04, Shotwell had no trouble importing photos from an iPhone 7.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Shotwell bug not iPhone/Apple restriction because I can use any file browser, open DCIM folder that I see mounted from iPhone and add, copy or delete images from it.

Answer (score 0):

I can access documents on the iPhone 6 but I keeps getting:

> could not claim USB devices (-53)

Shotwell used to work on previous iOS versions, but current ones prevent it or only partially do it. Sometimes it only gets the latest pictures. It could be encryption in `IMG_xxxxx.JPG` files. People may have to put your pictures in documents and move them to pictures for the mean time.

Update: Ubuntu has trouble mounting iPhones, it should show up as a separate driving named iPhone: showing a DCIM folder with `101APPLE` folder and/or `100APPLE` folder containing all of your pictures.

Still getting I/O errors and USB issues when syncing or copy/transferring what shows up between devices.